# Selenium click on area not working

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

I have image with numbers,i build some method that return where all the number area and they area id,but when i do click nothing  happens.

Here html code of area:

```
<map id="tc_tclavier1438161670450" style="display:block" name="tc_tclavier1438161670450">
<area id="touche11" class="touche" coords="0,0,24,24" style="cursor: pointer;display:block;">
<area id="touche12" class="toucheVide" coords="24,0,48,24" style="cursor: pointer;display:block;">
<area id="touche13" class="touche" coords="48,0,72,24" style="cursor: pointer;display:block;">
<area id="touche14" class="toucheVide" coords="72,0,96,24" style="cursor: pointer;display:block;">
<area id="touche21" class="touche" coords="0,24,24,48" style="cursor: pointer;display:block;">
<area id="touche22" class="toucheVide" coords="24,24,48,48" style="cursor: pointer;display:block;">
<area id="touche23" class="touche" coords="48,24,72,48" style="cursor: pointer;display:block;">
<area id="touche24" class="toucheVide" coords="72,24,96,48" style="cursor: pointer;display:block;">
 </map>
```

After i used my method i know where all number and have they id's,i trying to click on area ,but in not working.

Here what i tryied:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("touche13")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("touche13")).SendKeys(Keys.Return);
```

Do any one know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with Xpath Path and Css Selector statement